# Understanding SyntaxError in ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, syntaxerror

On the line after the field info I continue to get syntax errors and I'm unable to solve this problem myself, please help me.
The purpose of the code is to move a given point within a set distance in order to protect privacy of said point

```
# Step 11 - SELECT By Attributes -> where FID == FID_1, export to new Feature Class
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Make a layer from the feature class
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(in_features="RDiff_AreaIntersect_Dissolve", out_layer="lyr_eaten",
where_clause="",
workspace="",
field_info= "OBJECTID OBJECTID VISIBLE NONE", "Shape Shape VISIBLE NONE",     "ORIG_FID ORIG_FID VISIBLE NONE", "FIRST_Join_Count FIRST_Join_Count VISIBLE NONE"
FIRST_OBJECTID_1 FIRST_OBJECTID_1 VISIBLE None,
FIRST_gps_latitu FIRST_gps_latitu VISIBLE None,
FIRST_gps_longit FIRST_gps_longit VISIBLE None,
FIRST_OBJECTID FIRST_OBJECTID VISIBLE None,
FIRST_R1 FIRST_R1 VISIBLE None,
FIRST_ORIG_FID FIRST_ORIG_FID VISIBLE None,
Shape_Length Shape_Length VISIBLE None,
Shape_Area Shape_Area VISIBLE None)
```

Comment: You need quotation marks for all fields, like you have on OBJECTID and Shape. From what I can see you dont need to use field_info since you set all fields to VISIBLE and with no split policy and this is default with MakeFeatureLayer: `arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(in_features="RDiff_AreaIntersect_Dissolve", out_layer="lyr_eaten")` should be enough.

Comment: To compliment @BERA if you ran the make FeatureLayer tool in Arcmap then go to geo-processing history, right click on tool you just ran and copy snippet into notepad, this will show you EXACTLY how the syntax of the tool should be. Useful for fiddly parameters like fieldmap.